# Excel/Google Sheets: Find MAX Value (Based on Adjacent Cell) + Add 1

Tags: excel, google-sheets, max, match, vlookup

Looking for help with either Excel or Google Sheets. Two Columns: A | B.

Need to increment B value by `1` based off of the MAX value in B that is matched in column A.

Trying to accomplish an auto increment (+1) based off of the MAX value in column B of a department in column A.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoIcu.png]

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into cell B1:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1;$A1)
```

and copy it down the B column

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an array-solution (in Google Spreadsheets), then given your data try in cell B1:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(A1:A),SORT(ROW(A1:A),A1:A,1),1)-MATCH(A1:A,SORT(A1:A),0)-ROW()+2))
```

If you want the returned values formatted with leading zeroes, click the 123-button in the menu >> choose 'More Formats' >> then: 'Custom number format...' and in the box on top enter: `00#`. That should do it.

[Example spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMFBASgwDS-Putao4MD89yH2Wyz5FE3O4gAOrvFBQEs/edit?usp=sharing)